# Pattern matching in Python Insightconnet workflow

Tags: python, regex, workflow, rapid7

I have a workflow that retrieves a CVE name and number. I can get it to print to Teams juts fine as is. However I am attempting to scrape ONLY the CVE number "CVE-2021-XXXXX"

When it runs as:

```
import re
text ="{{["Get Vulnerability Content from Rapid7 Vuln DB"].[content_result].[title]}}"

m = re.search(r'CVE-\d{4}-\d{4,7}', text)

if m:
    found = m.group(1)
```

I receive the following output:

```
rapid7/Python 3 Script:2.0.3. Step name: run
Input: (below)

{}

Function: (below)

import re

text ="Google Chrome Vulnerability: CVE-2021-XXXX "Long description"

m = re.search(r'CVE-\d{4}-\d{4,7}', text)

if m:
    found = m.group(1)

Could not run supplied script. Error: no such group
```

I tried print() and Out as well.

It is in a loop so it will only be scraping one line of text at a time.

Comment: I see the string literal is not closed correctly, try using single quotation marks. `text ='{{['Get Vulnerability Content from Rapid7 Vuln DB'].[content_result].[title]}}'` and note - **you CAN'T use `m.group(1)` here**, there is no group in your regex. Replace `m.group(1)` with `m.group()`.

Comment: No dice. Get the same error but it does show up as:
text ='Google Chrome Vulnerability: CVE-2021-XXXX Long Description'
Could not run supplied script. Error: 're\n\ntext'

Comment: Yeah, something is wrong with the syntax, but we cannot help you without being able to repro this issue. As I say, you must use `m.group()` to fix the obvious issue, but it seems it is not fixing the whole code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.findall` here:

```py
text = 'Google Chrome Vulnerability: CVE-2021-XXXX "Long description"'
matches = re.findall(r'\bCVE-\d{4}-\w{4,7}\b', text)
print(matches)  # ['CVE-2021-XXXX']
```

Comment: Unfortunately now I get:
Could not run supplied script. Error: 're\n\ntext'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/python_3_script_rapid7_plugin-2.0.3-py3.7.egg/komand_python_3_script/actions/run/action.py", line 22, in run
    out = locals()[funcname](params["input"])
KeyError: 're\n\ntext'